# Qt QVector of multidimensional array

Tags: c++, qt, multidimensional-array, qvector

I'm trying to create a QVector of multidimensional array(C++ array class) but I'm facing troubles with it

I have a class "node" and I want to pass the QVector of a multidimensional array as a parameter of the node class construct but this isn't working, I'm a getting a compile error!

```
Class node {
    node(QVector<array<array<int, SIZE>, SIZE>> v);
}
```

any one has an idea of how should I proceed?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: @sjdowling the error is: "expected ')' before '<' token"

Comment: @vahancho array is the C++ array class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> node(QVector, SIZE>> v);

That will *not* compile without C++11 and on. You need two ways to address it:

### Pre-C++11

```
node(QVector<array<array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> > v);
//                                        ^space
```

### C++11 and post

```
node(QVector<array<array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> > v);
```

Correct, [no change; it just works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket). Put this into your qmake project file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

However, since you seem to use "C++ array", you will need the latter solution. In other words, just add c++11 compilation support to you build.

You have further issues, too:

- I am not sure where you got the idea of capital for the `Class`. It should be written `class`.
- Also, you inherently need the separator (`;`) after a class.
- You better do not use `array` in header files, but `std::array`.

This is my working example:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QVector>
#include <array>

const int SIZE = 5;

class node {
    node(QVector<std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE>> v) {}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add space between `>>`. For example:

```
class node {
    node(QVector<array<array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> > v);//space here!
};//don't forget
```

You need this space because compiler think that you want to use `>>` operator.

Comment: Wrong, actually you do *not* need it with C++11.

Comment: @lpapp I removed comment a few moments ago because I understood what did you try to say, about this space, not about std::array. Yes, you are right.

Comment: @lpapp Your answer is definitely better and I will delete my answer, but first of all I want to ask, why after adding space, OP has no errors? If he activate C++11 support, then it should work without errors? Maybe it is specification of OP's compiler?

Comment: @Chernobyl: someone found your answer useful, so I would not delete it. :) I am not sure what compiler the OP uses. Gcc implemented right angle bracket in 4.3, so the earliest gcc version supporting some C++11 and the same for VS2010 (msvc). Therefore, if std::array works, that should, too, but then again, the OP might be using some different compiler or just messing around without understanding. It is also possible he has a non-C++11 compatible compiler with array extension.

Comment: @lpapp actually i had C++11 support activated and i had the error when i didn't add the space

Comment: @user3521418: what compiler, which version, which platform? What do you mean by "activated"? In the project file or to the compiler directly, somewhere else? How exactly did you enable it? Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Can you check my SSCCE whether it works?

Comment: @lpapp I understood all, so I removed line with `config` from my answer, but anyways your answer is very good and I found it very useful at least for me(because I didn't know about that before and add this space everytime), so I upvoted it earlier. Thank you!